# MATLAB Simulink Model Configuration Parameters: Empty Window

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am currently working with Simulink and out of the sudden, I am unable to change the Model Configuration Parameters.

Whether I try to open the window via RightClick->Model Configuration Parameters or via Ctrl+E, in both cases, a blank white window opens.

This problem persists after a reboot and opening/closing MATLAB. Furthermore, it is the case for any model (whether old, new, untouched, example...) on my computer. Yesterday I searched for 45min for possible solutions but could not find any.

Is there some graphics cache or can you think of another way, how I could get the dialog back? A photo is attached:

[Screenshot: Configuration Parameters window stays blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmmn3.png)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens in Academic version on Simulink. I have not seen it in Original software.

A solution for your problem can be :

1) clear cache of Simulink by typeing the following command in command window :

```
rehash toolboxcache
```

2) reset menu and toolbar of Simulink by the following command :

```
sl_refresh_customizations
```

Then close **MATLAB** by `exit` command.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I cannot test it, because I made a fresh install (I really needed Simulink to work). Though it might be a solution, since I do use the academic version with the licence of my university.